# How to use Repl Xcode 7? Getting error for absolute path

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, swift2, ios9

I wanted to use REPL for Swift with XCode-7 Public Beta installed on my system. But an attempt to run via the absolute path in the terminal window like this:

```
$ cd /Applications
$ ./Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift
```

throws an error --

```
<unknown>:0: error: Swift does not support the SDK 'MacOSX10.10.sdk'
```

Is there a setting I'm missing for the SDK? I tried to search for it, and went through the Release notes too, but to no avail :(

Comment: what error said MACOSX10.10 not supported.

Comment: iMac:bin $ ./swift
<unknown>:0: error: Swift does not support the SDK 'MacOSX10.10.sdk'

Answer (score 1):

I found an article which was discussing Xcode 7 and Swift 2 supported frameworks, and they mentioned xcode-select in the discussion. There was also a way to change the setting via the location tab in XCode preferences. 
Changing the setting - "Command Line Tools:" (The last setting in the Locations tab) to "Xcode 7.0 (7a121l)" worked, I can run Repl now in the terminal window.

However, I do get an error, before the Repl starts,

```
error: libarclite_macosx.a(arclite.o) failed to load objfile for /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_macosx.a
Welcome to Apple Swift version 2.0 (700.0.42.1 700.0.53). Type :help for assistance.
```

But it works fine after that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Swift REPL in all your Xcode version installed.

Mind the version of the current Swift installed

```
$ xcrun swift --version

Apple Swift version 1.2 (swiftlang-602.0.53.1 clang-602.0.53)
```

If you want use the beta version, you have to switch to it

```
$ sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app
```

to obtain

```
$ xcrun swift --version

Apple Swift version 2.0 (swiftlang-700.0.45 clang-700.0.57.2)
```

If you want switch between both versions often, you can create a simple bash script with aliases (e.g. swiftTools.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash

alias swift="xcrun swift"
alias swift1='sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app; swift'
alias swift2='sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app; swift'
```

and then add it in the .bash_profile

```
source ~/scripts/swiftTools.sh
```

To use aliases in the same session of your terminal instance you have to use "source" and not "sh"

The result is

```
$ swift1
Welcome to Swift version 1.2. Type :help for assistance.
 1>  

$ swift2
Welcome to Apple Swift version 2.0 (700.0.45 700.0.57.2). Type :help for assistance.
 1>
```